# Best way to send zip file as response in Azure functions using node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, zip, azure-functions

Using Azure function app, I want to be able to download images from different urls to a particular folder, zip them and send the zip file back in the response.

I'm able to acheive this by following the below steps:

1. request for the file
2. Save the file locally
3. Zip the directory using
4. archiver read the Zipped file, convert it to base64
5. send the buffer in the response body

Download and save image

```
const img = await request(url, { encoding: "binary" });
fs.writeFile(filesName, data, "binary", err => {
    if (err) {
        reject(`Error while writing the file; ${err}`);
    } else {
        resolve(data);
    }
});
```

Zip the directory, read the Zipped file and send the response

```
const target = await zipDirectory(dirName, targetFile);
context.log('Target ' + targetFile);
const rawFile = await readFile(targetFile);
const fileBuffer = Buffer.from(rawFile, "base64");
context.res = {
    body: fileBuffer,
    headers: {
    "Content-Disposition": `filename=target.zip`,
    "Content-Type": "application/zip"
},
status: 202
};
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a function with an `http` trigger, where the input would be the uri of the image, and an output binding of a blob container. The logic would be to save the image in blob storage.
2. Create another function that is blob-triggered, which would grab the file, zip it, and it can have an output blob binding. It would zip the file and place it in your output blob binding.
3. Your zipped file would be in the output blob container.

Alternatively you can orchestrate that entire process with a durable function.